# Controle de acesso em API usando Flask JWT Extended

Tags: python, api, segurança, flask, jwt

Estou trabalhando em uma API (Flask/Python) que deve receber requisições de um aplicativo (React-Native) e um Webapp (Flask/Python). Para algumas requisições será necessário o controle de login. Para isso estou usando autenticação por meio de JWTs (biblioteca Flask-JWT-Extended). Para autenticação no Webapp um post é feito na rota `/auth/login` da API e um token é retornado caso os dados estejam corretos:

```
@users.route("/auth/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
   data = request.get_json()
   if data['email'] and data['password']:
       user = User.query.filter_by(email=data['email']).one_or_none()
       if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, data['password']):
           response_object = jsonify({'message': 'Success. Login successful'})
        access_token = create_access_token(identity=user)
        return jsonify(access_token=access_token)
   abort(jsonify(message="Wrong username or password"))
```

Minha dúvida é: como fazer o armazenamento desse token retornado pela API no meu Webapp (Flask/Python) para poder enviá-lo a cada requisição que o usuário fizer e, além disso, manter o usuário logado nesse app, pois ele também possui páginas que só podem acessadas por usuários autenticados.

Antes de ter uma API separada para as requisições que conversam diretamente com o banco de dados (quando eu tinha apenas o Webapp), eu estava usando o `Flask-login`, `login_user()` e `@login_required` para fazer esse controle, mas não posso mais seguir esse caminho pois o `app` também precisa ser atendido pelo API.